# Python: Raw socket causing WinError 10013

Tags: python, sockets

I am creating a packet sniffer (yes the hard way with `socket`) and using the following code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
while True:
    print(s.recvfrom(2048))
```

Which gives this error: `OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`.
Through removing different things, I have determined that using a raw socket (`socket.SOCK_RAW`) is the issue, but there is no alternative to this. Can someone explain why I'm getting this error and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure file is being run with admin.